# How the finite cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}_p$ can be endowed with discrete topology to make it a topological group?

Tags: topological-groups

How the finite cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}_p$ can be endowed with discrete topology to make it a topological group?

We have information that in discrete topology all subsets of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is open set and it is the largest topology on $\Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: See your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327951/what-is-the-topology-on-the-group-g-prod-n-1-infty-mathbbz-pn-can). [Every group can be trivially made into a topological group by considering it with the discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group).

Comment: A topological group is a group with a topology where the group operation and inverse are continuous; $\Bbb Z_p$ is a group, the discrete topology is a topology, and any function from a discrete topological space is continuous

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks for your valuable comment and in fact it helped me a lot

Comment: Do you see that $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x\ne y$, $d(x,y)=0$ otherwise is a **metric** on $G$ ? This makes $G$ into a topological group. This metric is the discrete metric. Any function from $G \to \Bbb{C}$ is continuous and the Haar measure (ie. the $G$-invariant integral) is $\int_G f(x)dx = \sum_{x \in G} f(x)$

Comment: @reuns, thanks for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [topological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group) is a group with a topology where the group operation and inverse are continuous.

$\Bbb Z_p$ is a group, the discrete topology is a topology, and any function from a discrete topological space is continuous.

Indeed, as pointed out in the comment by [Dietrich Burde](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83966/dietrich-burde), any group can be trivially made into a topological group by considering it with the discrete topology.

Comment: Or the trivial topology, if you do not insist on your topological groups being Hausdorff.

Comment: @J.W. Tanner,  the inverse map $f: \Bbb{Z}_p \to \Bbb{Z}_p$ is continuous but how to see that the map $g:\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p \to \Bbb{Z}_p$ is continuous ? Because in this case $\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p$ is not discrete topological space.